# Compile-time Type Parameters with Multiple Bounds

Tags: java, generics, type-parameter, type-bounds

Can I use Type Parameters with multiple bounds to guarantee at compile-time that a container's contents conform to certain traits?

This is probably best expressed in code:

```java
public class TestCase {

    // our base type
    public static abstract class Animal { }

    // a container of animals, but we'd like to restrict to certain kinds
    public static class Zoo<T extends Animal> {
        private List<T> animals = new ArrayList<>();
        public void addAnimal(T animal) {
            this.animals.add(animal);
        }
        public List<T> getAnimals() {
            return Collections.unmodifiableList(animals);
        }
    }

    // Animal traits - we want to build a Zoo to only house animals with some traits
    public static interface Bird {}
    public static interface Mammal {}
    public static interface Large {}

    // An assortment of animals with different traits
    public static class Sparrow extends Animal implements Bird { }
    public static class Ostrich extends Animal implements Bird, Large { }
    public static class Meerkat extends Animal implements Mammal { }
    public static class Buffalo extends Animal implements Mammal, Large { }

    // some different types of zoos we could build
    public static class BirdZoo<T extends Animal & Bird> extends Zoo<T> {}
    public static class LargeAnimalZoo<T extends Animal & Large> extends Zoo<T> {}
    public static class LargeMammalZoo<T extends Animal & Large & Mammal> extends Zoo<T> {}

    // BirdZoo should accept Ostrich & Sparrow, not Meerkat or Buffalo
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        BirdZoo rawBirdZoo = new BirdZoo();
        rawBirdZoo.addAnimal(new Ostrich()); // warning - unchecked
        rawBirdZoo.addAnimal(new Sparrow()); // warning - unchecked
        rawBirdZoo.addAnimal(new Meerkat()); // warning - unchecked
        rawBirdZoo.addAnimal(new Buffalo()); // warning - unchecked

        BirdZoo<?> wildBirdZoo = new BirdZoo<>();
        wildBirdZoo.addAnimal(new Ostrich()); // error - incompatible types
        wildBirdZoo.addAnimal(new Sparrow()); // error - incompatible types
        wildBirdZoo.addAnimal(new Meerkat()); // error - incompatible types
        wildBirdZoo.addAnimal(new Buffalo()); // error - incompatible types

        BirdZoo<? extends Bird> boundedBirdZoo_B = new BirdZoo<>();
        boundedBirdZoo_B.addAnimal(new Ostrich()); // error - incompatible types
        boundedBirdZoo_B.addAnimal(new Sparrow()); // error - incompatible types
        boundedBirdZoo_B.addAnimal(new Meerkat()); // error - incompatible types
        boundedBirdZoo_B.addAnimal(new Buffalo()); // error - incompatible types

        BirdZoo<? extends Animal> boundedBirdZoo_A = new BirdZoo();
        boundedBirdZoo_A.addAnimal(new Ostrich()); // error - incompatible types
        boundedBirdZoo_A.addAnimal(new Sparrow()); // error - incompatible types
        boundedBirdZoo_A.addAnimal(new Meerkat()); // error - incompatible types
        boundedBirdZoo_A.addAnimal(new Buffalo()); // error - incompatible types

        BirdZoo<Ostrich> ostrichZoo = new BirdZoo<>();
        ostrichZoo.addAnimal(new Ostrich());
        ostrichZoo.addAnimal(new Sparrow()); // error - incompatible types
        ostrichZoo.addAnimal(new Meerkat()); // error - incompatible types
        ostrichZoo.addAnimal(new Buffalo()); // error - incompatible types
    }
}
```

What I want is for BirdZoo to accept both Ostrich and Sparrow, and reject Meerkat and Buffalo.  Is there any other way to construct such a container?

Comment: Why should `BirdZoo` extend `Animal`?

Comment: @NicholasK it doesn't, but its type parameter does.  `BirdZoo` itself extends `Zoo`, and its type parameter extends `Animal`, because all `Zoo`s must contain `Animal`s.

Comment: @Derefacto Yeah, saw that.  The question is whether you use that to create a container with compile-time guarantees that its contents conform to all bounds?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, no you can't. The conceptual reason is in how generic types are bound. When you create a class like `Zoo<T extends Animal>`, `T` *doesn't* mean "any type that extends `Animal`", it means, "a specific type that extends `Animal` that will be provided at runtime". Normally this lets you do what you want, but your case appears to be testing the bounds (ba-dum-tiss) of this system.

I think the more nitty-gritty answer will have to go into the wildcard (`?`) binding system - something about `? extends A & B` means that it can't prove that a type `C` that extends `A & B & D` actually matches.

A (worse) design that accomplishes your goal looks like this:

```
  public static abstract class Zoo{
    private List<Animal> animals = new ArrayList<>();

    protected void addAnimalHelper(Animal animal) {
      this.animals.add(animal);
    }
  }

  public static class BirdZoo extends Zoo {
    public <T extends Animal & Bird> void addAnimal(T animal) {
      addAnimalHelper(animal);
    }
  }

  BirdZoo birdZoo = new BirdZoo();
  birdZoo.addAnimal(new Ostrich()); // ok
  birdZoo.addAnimal(new Sparrow()); // ok
  birdZoo.addAnimal(new Meerkat()); // Meekrat doesn't conform to Bird
  birdZoo.addAnimal(new Buffalo()); // Buffalo doesn't conform to Bird
```

With the type parameter encoded in the method signature, the type system is free to pick a new `T` with each method call, which allows it to bind to Ostrich on one call and Sparrow on the next.

Obviously, this has some downsides compared to your desired design:

1. Underlying storage is "raw" (in this case just `Animal`), it's up to typed subclass to enforce typing of elements
2. Similarly, getting elements out of storage and keeping known type is hard / messy.
3. Requires boilerplate method in each subclass + access to helper to encode type in methods.

---

Another option that only works part of the way:

```
  // Note - inheritance isn't used here since it breaks due to method overriding issues.
  public static class BirdZoo<T extends Animal & Bird> {
    private List<T> animals = new ArrayList<>();
    public <X extends Animal & Bird> void addAnimal(X animal) {
      this.animals.add((T)animal); // Unchecked cast warning
    }
    public List<T> getAnimals() {
      return Collections.unmodifiableList(animals);
    }
  }

  BirdZoo<?> wildBirdZoo = new BirdZoo<>();
  wildBirdZoo.addAnimal(new Ostrich()); // ok
  wildBirdZoo.addAnimal(new Sparrow()); // ok
  wildBirdZoo.addAnimal(new Meerkat()); // error - incompatible types
  wildBirdZoo.addAnimal(new Buffalo()); // error - incompatible types
```

The fact that it complains about casting `X` to `T` sort of indicates the issue we're dancing around. For example, when the instance is constructed with `BirdZoo<?>`, we're mostly ok. On the other hand, imagine the zoo was constructed using `BirdZoo<Ostrich>` and `ostrichBirdZoo.addAnimal(new Sparrow());` is called. Then we have `T=Ostrich` and `X=Sparrow`. Both `T` and `X` extend both `Animal` and `Bird`, but `T != X`, **BUT** the static nor type checker isn't smart enough to tell!

```
BirdZoo<?> wildBirdZoo = new BirdZoo<>();
wildBirdZoo.addAnimal(new Ostrich()); // ok
wildBirdZoo.addAnimal(new Sparrow()); // ok

BirdZoo<Ostrich> ostrichBirdZoo = new BirdZoo<>();
ostrichBirdZoo.addAnimal(new Ostrich()); // ok
ostrichBirdZoo.addAnimal(new Sparrow()); // ok and doesn't throw at runtime --> Sparrow to Ostrich cast succeeds.

System.out.println(wildBirdZoo.getAnimals());
System.out.println(ostrichBirdZoo.getAnimals()); // Contains a sparrow...?
```

Which seems to break the type system entirely.

---

So long story short... this may not work the way you want.

Comment: Excellent answer, thank you!!  `it means, "a specific type that extends Animal that will be provided at runtime"` -- I shall remember this way of thinking about bounded type params.